# pg_connect not working with PHP 5

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm working on an application that runs fine with PHP 4 in a windows 8 server. I'm setting a local server with postgres to work locally but with PHP 5 to migrate a few things. I'm having some compatibility issues but nothing big except that the pg_connect function in a class is not working and is not throwing me any error

```
class basededatos{
    var $link_;

    function basededatos(){
        $this->link_=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=... user=postgres password=...") or die('Falla en la conexión a la Base de Datos. Por favor, Revise la Configuración.');
    }

    function cerrarconexion(){
        pg_close($this->link_);
    }

    function Abreconexionconretorno($consulta){
        $resultado=pg_query($consulta)or die("La consulta falló con error: ".pg_last_error());
        return $resultado;
    }

    function Abreconexionsinretorno($consulta){
        pg_query($consulta)or die("La consulta falló con error: ".pg_last_error());
    }
}
```

After this

```
$this->link_=pg_connect(...)
```

It just dies, any idea why is this happenning? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you don't have PostreSQL extension enabled in php.ini file because You upgraded to PHP 5. Just add this line to php.ini if pgsql module for PHP is installed:

`extension=php_pgsql.dll` (windows)

`extension=php_pgsql.so` (linux)

If the module is not installed then go with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would give an error if it was not installed

Comment: Tried to connect php with postgres sql not working. Atlast it is working in windows following your way